# Read user input until it matches a given number

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
public class JavaAsig8 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;

    System.out.print("Enter a whole number: ");
    number = stdIn.nextInt();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int answer = rn.nextInt(10) + 1;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
  }
}
```

I need to be able to ask the user to guess the number until it is equal to random number.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int givenNumber = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a whole number: ");
         while(true)
         {
             if(s.nextInt() == givenNumber)
             {
                 System.out.println("You guessed it right! Answer is: " + givenNumber);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```